# Is there a Steam Player Ranking?

Tags: steam

It could be an external site, or Steam itself. I believe there should be a ranking of the best players in terms of most achievements, perfect games and owned games.

Comment: A quick Google search yielded Steam Ladder, but I'm voting this question as off-topic since it is asking for recommendations of services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam has no built-in options for this and, while there is an API for third-party sites, it's limited by user privacy settings.  That said, there are sites that give some stats.  Searching for a specific stat you are looking for will likely yield a few results, but here's a couple sites with common stats:

- [most achievements](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/TopList.php?DisplayType=1), as well as quite a few other top lists.
- [highest level](https://steamdb.info/stats/toplevels/), along with stats for badges